# Form to accept a record and multiple associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, form-for

If a user has_many skills, and a skill belongs_to a user:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skills
  validates_length_of :skills, maximum: 5
end
```

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_associated :user
end
```

how can a form be made that accepts the user and ***multiple*** skills?

Here is a form with the user and *one* skill, but I can't work out how to make it accept multiple skills in the same form?

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> 
  
  <%= f.label :bio %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :bio %>

   <%= fields_for "user[skill]", @user.skill do |skill_fields| %>
      <%= f.label :skill %><br>
      <%= skill_fields.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Apply", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Note, it's fine for the (5) fields to be on screen rather than generated dynamically with javascript.

Comment: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon - Check whether it helps

Comment: @user11350468 appreciate it, I'll look into cocoon. For now I think I prefer to use vanilla rails if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### accepts_nested_attributes_for

You can consider using **Rails** built-in `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Please, have a look at the [Active Record Nested Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) docs, especially in the `One-to-many` section.

And this is the official guide on how to generate a Rails form for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - [10 Building Complex Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms).

Comment: Thanks, I read the whole of the first link already, but no code for the view in it :( I also read the second link (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) , but I missed section 10.2, so I'll try that now

Comment: I realised 10.2 has only one address for the Person. But in my example, I need multiple addresses for the Person. Is it possible to show how to do that in the view?

Comment: Sorry, but it is a little bit unclear to me, why are you saying that `10.2 has only one address for the Person`? If I am not missing something, the Person class from 10.1 Configuring the Model has_many :addresses.

Comment: Maybe, a RailsCast will help? http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Thanks I will check out the rails cast. When I follow the instructions in 10.2, I check using the debugger and the 5 records are created in the view, but the form only generates a single form field. So the user can only enter one, not many

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing, my code is the same as in 10.2. Does it automatically know to make more than one field, or should I create a loop? (I blindly/exactly followed section 10.2)

Comment: Agh, it worked, I was forgetting the `form` before `form.fields_for` !